# Half of an HTML element disappears when being hidden via jQuery UI '.hide()'

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have an HTML element that, when clicked, slides up/down/left/right (depending on user settings) using the jQuery UI `.hide()` function.

```
$('#abb-wrap').hide('slide', { 'direction': 'up' }, 200, function(){

    // I do stuff here, but it's not relevant (and not causing the problem)

});
```

This function works perfectly, but half of the HTML element disappears during the animation.  I'm using `transform: translateX(50%);` in order to position the element exactly where it needs to go, and presumably this is the root cause of the problem.

However, after much searching and testing of possible solutions, I cannot figure out how to fix the problem.  Has anyone come across this problem before, and if so, what is the solution?

Here is the HTML element in question (literally all of it, it's very simple) -

```
<div id="abb-wrap">
    <span class="button-text">Show Admin Bar</span>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS used to style the element, as rendered by Firefox 44.0.2 (the problem also persists in IE9/10/11 and Chrome 43.0.2357.81) -

```
#abb-wrap {
    background-color:   #23282d !important;
    background-repeat:  repeat;
    bottom:             auto;
    color:              #9ea3a8 !important;
    cursor:             pointer;
    height:             32px;
    left:               auto;
    position:           fixed;
    right:              50%;
    top:                0;
    transform:          translateX(50%);
    z-index:            100000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the position of the outer wrapper is fixed, it will not affect the relative positioning of the other elements. With that, a workaround that I did was to make the width of the wrapper to be 100% and apply the background to the inner span. You can add additional styling to this span:

```
#abb-wrap {
    bottom:             auto;
    color:              #9ea3a8 !important;
    cursor:             pointer;
    height:             32px;
    position:           fixed;
    top:                0;
    z-index:            100000;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

.button-text{
  background-color:   #23282d !important;
  background-repeat:  repeat;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

See the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xfnf49sa/1/

Note that I increased the time of the effect to show it clearer. Also note that the `text-align:center` is required here for the outer wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your call to "hide" may be using the wrong syntax.

[jQuery: .hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/#hide-duration-easing-complete)

> .hide( duration [, easing ] [, complete ] )

And, the easing function is more of how the animation moves and not so much the direction. To have the button slide up, it may be better to use the .slideUp method.

[jQuery: .slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/)

Then, you could do...

```
$('#abb-wrap').slideUp("slow", function () { ... });
```

Here is a fiddle with an example.

https://jsfiddle.net/wvh47s5L/

Comment: It's the jQuery UI `.hide()` function, the syntax is correct. I've update my question to ensure that this is clear. Thanks.

Comment: Ah. Well, you've exposed my jQuery UI ignorance. Luckily, A. Sharma appears to have a solution. Sorry about that.